# How to query the data storage time (not the original data generation time) of time series in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I checked the official website and the questions here, and know that the timestamp in Apache IoTDB is referred to the time that the data has uploaded. Therefore, I want to know how to check the time when data was stored into IoTDB? If I want to query this data enter time, what settings can I use in IoTDB to store this data, while still keeping the original timestamp (data upload time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time that the data entered Apache IoTDB (which should be what you mean) will not be recorded by default. If you need to retain this data, you can add a field called `insertTime` to each device in IoTDB, and manually assign the current time to that time series every time you write data into IoTDB.